# Run a function for a specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simulate a roulette wheel, displaying random numbers and background color (black or red) every 1/10 second. The code below is working as desired, however I would like the function to run only for a specific amount of time, like 5 seconds. I think I need to use setTimeout(), but I can't get it to work with the code below.

```
$('#spin').click(function(){
function spinWheel() {
    var rouletteNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 36) + 1);
    $('#rouletteWheel').html(rouletteNum);
    var color = ['red', 'black']
    var i = [Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
    $('#rouletteWheel').css('background-color', color[i]);
}
   setInterval(spinWheel, 100);
});
```

Comment: Have you ever played at a roulette table? Each number has a designated colour, so what you're doing here violates that design :)

Comment: It's also missing the green zero, btw (and 00 for american).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to use a counter

```
$('#spin').click(function () {
    var counter = 0,
        loopCount = 50 //10 times in a  second * 5 seconds
        ;


    function spinWheel() {
        if (++counter >= loopCount) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        var rouletteNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 36) + 1);
        $('#rouletteWheel').html(rouletteNum);
        var color = ['red', 'black']
        var i = [Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
        $('#rouletteWheel').css('background-color', color[i]);
    }
    var interval = setInterval(spinWheel, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this we can use the `Date` object. Which gets the number of milliseconds since around 1970. So we defined a starting time with `Date.now()` and call it `start` then 5 seconds later would be: `end = start + 5000`. Then we will update `start` each time we call our function, once `start` goes past `end` we need to end our interval with `clear interval`.

```
var start = Date.now(); // The current date (in miliseconds)
var end = start + 5000; // 5 seconds afterwords

function spinWheel() {
    start = Date.now(); // Get the date currently
    /* Your code here */
    if(start > end) clearInterval(timer); // If we are 5 seconds later clear interval
}
var timer = setInterval(spinWheel, 100);
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoLjkyy5/)** - Notice it stops after 5 seconds

**Notice:** You can use a counter in this case as well, but if you want your time to be directly after 5 seconds and be accurate, it's not recommend, as it's possible for `setInterval()` to drift. But it will be quite close most of the time. *Date* will be more accurate. If you are just looking for "very close to or at 5 seconds", doing a counter will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can clear your interval after for example 10 times.

```
    $('#spin').click(function(){
    counter = 0;
    howManyTimes = 10;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        counter++
            if(counter === howManyTimes) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                alert('game over');
            } else {
                var rouletteNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 36) + 1);
                $('#rouletteWheel').html(rouletteNum);
                var color = ['red', 'black']
                var i = [Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length)];
                $('#rouletteWheel').css('background-color', color[i]);
            }
    },100);

   interval();
});
```

working example [jsfiddle clear interval](http://jsfiddle.net/jpg5dd06/)