# Run code block for n seconds in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need to run a block of code for only 60 seconds in node js.

```
function someFunc()
{
    console.log("hello");
    //event occurs - so time should increase by 5 secs.
}
```

On a particular event, the time should increase further by 5 seconds. How do I achieve this?
`setTimeout` doesn't work since it starts running after 60 seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a function for a specific amount of time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030920/run-a-function-for-a-specific-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution, But almost nearer to your requirement. Comments will explain code.

Click button to increment 5 more seconds. Just used button for event. You may replace that with your custom event.

```js
var timer = 0; //A timer for execution

var initialTime = 5000; //This is your 60 seconds, change this

var func = function(){ //code block to execcute after time
  console.log("Hello"); 
  console.log(initialTime); //gives 0 Just to check timeout. 
};

var timeOut; //timeOutId

timeOut = setTimeout(func, initialTime); //initial timeOut

setInterval(function(){ //to run timer
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = ++timer;
  initialTime -= 1000; //reducing time from initially set Time
}, 1000);


function incrementer(){ //event to increase 5 more seconds
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  initialTime += 5000; //increasing by 5 seconds
  timeOut = setTimeout(func, initialTime); //updated timeOut
}
```

```html
<button onClick="incrementer()" id="timer"></button>
```